how to make a full and whole backup (or image backup) of a HP servers with linux os and Raid
I have two Hp proliant DL380 G7 and G6 servers.
Both servers have linux oracle 7.9 OS and One of the servers is raid 1 and another server is raid 5 .
I want to make a full backup (or full image backup) of these servers including all data, operating system, raids, etc. every weeks or every mounts (its not important to be automatic or manual).
and if happend any problem in the server then in case of failure servers I want to  restore the entire whole operating system with all its data to another disks.
so What is your suggestion for this backup model and how can I make a backup like this?
is there any software and method for this backup model ?
i dont want to use dd command or rsync command . i prefer to use any softwares to do these by itself and any other ways to make full backuo for restore on another disks whenever i need .
Thanks
best regard

if you have databases or some special aplication can be result in data corruption (that is applied to urbackup, restic file backups), you should test and backup additionally that things with another methods like xtrabackup, mysqldump in case of percona mysql:
i send you some software that i remember in case it is useful for you:

https://www.urbackup.org/

https://restic.net/

https://github.com/borgbackup/borg

https://duplicati.com/

https://www.percona.com/mysql/software/percona-xtrabackup


if you goal is press a enter and get a machine already restored you can use ansible, puppet, sh script if you really want bare metal or container engines like docker with jenkins, github actions etc, or virtual machine backups like pbs for proxmox

https://github.com/angristan/ansible-restic
https://pbs.proxmox.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page


thanks for your answer . yes i have oracle database in my oracle linux 7.9 and also many configs on my OS . so i will try your links . thank
